# CakePHP OR Condition Issue

Tags: cakephp

I have 2 models: MandrillEmail (email log) and Clients. I want to find a list of clients that either:

- HAVE NOT been sent a specific email
- OR HAVE been sent a specific email (email_content_id=5), but the last one was sent greater than 180 days ago.

Ultimately, I want to set this up to schedule an email to be sent every 180 days. I can easily accomplish the first task (checking to see if they have not been sent an email). The code is below (This works great):

```
$options['joins'][] = 
    array('table' => 'mandrill_emails',
    'alias' => 'MandrillEmail',
    'type' => 'LEFT',
    'conditions' => array(
        'MandrillEmail.client_id = Client.id',
        "MandrillEmail.email_content_id = 5"
    )
);

$options['conditions'][] = array(
    'MandrillEmail.id is NULL'
);
```

However, I'm not exactly sure how to modify the query to also check the 2nd statement above. Here's where I'm at:

```
 // check to see if the email HAS NOT been sent, or if it has, that it has been greater than 180 days
 $options['conditions'][] = array(
    'OR' => array(
        'MandrillEmail.id is NULL',
        array(
             "MandrillEmail.status" => 'SENT',  
             "MandrillEmail.created <" => $today_minus_180days
        )
    )
);
```

Another thing to keep in mind, this email should be sent every 180 days, so the OR statement check should only check the LAST entry.

Comment: Does your first one actually work? Doing a left join (seemingly from Client model?) should return all clients regardless of their association or lack thereof with a MandrillEmail.

Comment: What version of Cake, and what query is your second attempt generating?  Can you include the entire thing so we can see more than just the conditions?  At very least which model you're running this on..etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $options['joins'][] = array(
        'table' => 'mandrill_emails',
        'alias' => 'MandrillEmail',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'MandrillEmail.client_id = Client.id',
            'MandrillEmail.email_content_id' => 5,
            'MandrillEmail.status' => 'SENT',  
            'MandrillEmail.created <' => $today_minus_180days
        )
    );

    $this->Client->virtualFields['have_that_email'] = 'COUNT(MandrillEmail.id)';
```

If `have_that_email` is more than 0, email was send from last 180 days